# How to efficiently structure a batch queue processing logic flow

Tags: c#

I have a class that acts as a controller for websites. These exchanges take orders (think shopping cart). Some of the sites only allow you to have one active order/shoppingcart at a time, while others have no limitation.

My program will have a constant stream of items that need to be ordered/addedtocarts. For sites that can have an unlimited number of concurrent orders, this is not an issue, as I can just start up a new order as an item request comes in, but for sites that are limited, items will build up in a queue waiting to be processed when the current order is finished. The following is the code I have so far, and although admittingly there might be some holes or gotchas that I am not aware of (please point them out if this is the case), I think it is functional and will get the job done.

However, since the processing of an item, or queued items, can only be triggered by the addition of an item the while(Enabled) seems inefficent and wrong to me. I would like to restructure what I have to incorporate this logic, but I am not sure how to with the concurrency limitation in a thread-safe way.

```
class OrderItemTask
{
    public OrderStatus Status { get; private set; }
    public OrderItemParams Params { get; }
}

class SiteController
{
    public bool Enabled { get; private set; }

    //set in constructor, or options somewhere
    SemaphoreSlim maxConcurrency = new SemaphoreSlim( 1, 1 );

    Queue<OrderItemTask> itemQueue = new Queue<OrderItemTask>();

    public void Start()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Enabled = true;
            Task.Run( () => ProcessOrderWorker() );
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public OrderItemTask OrderItem(OrderItemParams @params)
    {
        var task = new OrderItemTask() { Params = @params};
        QueueItem( task );
        return task;
    }

    void QueueItem(OrderItemTask task)
     {
        lock (itemQueue)
        {
            itemQueue.Enqueue( task );
        }
    }

    async Task ProcessOrderWorker()
    {
        //while true or while SiteController is enabled 
        while (Enabled)
        {
            try
            {
                await maxConcurrency.WaitAsync();
                lock (itemQueue)
                {
                    if (itemQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var itemBatch = new List<OrderItemTask>();
                        while (itemQueue.Count > 0)
                            itemBatch.Add( itemQueue.Dequeue() );

                        placeOrderStrategy.PlaceOrder( itemBatch );
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { }
            finally
            {
                maxConcurrency.Release();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using  [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: `while (Enabled)` is dangerous without [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile).

Answer (score 0):

please look at the comments. I have the changes so it addresses your concerns

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Trader.Classes
{
    public class OrderItemParams
    {

    }

    public class OrderStatus
    {

    }

    public class SemaphoreSlim
    {
        public SemaphoreSlim(int a, int b)
        {

        }

        internal Task WaitAsync()
        {
            //do stuff, not sure what?
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        internal void Release()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class OrderItemTask
    {
        public OrderStatus Status
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public OrderItemParams Params
        {
            get;
            /*Sa6a: Added the set, as you were trying to assign it in public "OrderItemTask OrderItem(OrderItemParams @params)"
                    and it was telling you it is readonly */
            set;
        }
    }

    class SiteController
    {
        public bool Enabled { get; private set; }

        //set in constructor, or options somewhere
        SemaphoreSlim maxConcurrency = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

        //Queue<OrderItemTask> orderQueue = new Queue<OrderItemTask>();
        ConcurrentQueue<OrderItemTask> orderQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<OrderItemTask>(); //Sa6a: NET 4.0 and above
        List<Task> tList = new List<Task>(); //Sa6a: It is good to have reference to the tasks you are starting, so you can manage them better 

        /*Sa6a: I think you do not need that look at the QueueOrder method, I am leaving only start to true for now, 
                so we know that the whole thing is started and we can have a way to stop it if we want */
        public void Start()
        {
            Enabled = true;

            //lock (this)   //Sa6a: you do not need this lock, as this is not a method that can be accessed by more than one thread at a time
            //{
            //if (Enabled == false) //Sa6a: this might already be true, and if this is the case, you will end up starting another process
            //{
            //    Enabled = true;
            //    Task t = Task.Run(() => ProcessOrderWorker());
            //    tList.Add(t);
            //}
            //}
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            //lock (this)  //Sa6a: you do not need this lock, as this is not a method that can be accessed by more than one thread at a time
            //{
            Enabled = false;
            tList.Clear();
            //}
        }

        public OrderItemTask OrderItem(OrderItemParams @params)
        {
            var task = new OrderItemTask() { Params = @params };
            QueueOrder(task);
            return task;
        }


        public void QueueOrder(OrderItemTask task)
        {
            /* Sa6a: MSN documentation does not say that Eqnqueue can throw an error, but call it a 6th sense, just have the catch
             * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8
             */
            try
            {
                if (Enabled)
                {
                    //Remove the completed tasks
                foreach(Task t in tList)
                {
                    if (t.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        tList.Remove(t);
                    }
                }

                orderQueue.Enqueue(task);

                //Sa6a: Start the task here if it is not runningg anymore. 
                if (tList.Count == 0)
                {
                    Task t = Task.Run(() => ProcessOrderWorker());
                    tList.Add(t);
                }                    }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I do not know if we need this, but the idea is if this is stopped, " +
                            "you should stop enqueuing items, and you can do this onkly if the start method is called. Another way would be to set Enabled to true automatically here?");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This should never happen in theoery - " + ex);
            }
        }

        /* Sa6a: So the way I have it below is that once the items are dequeued, it should exit the task,
         *       however I am not sure what these maxConcurrency objects do, so if they make it run again, you should remove them
         */
        async Task ProcessOrderWorker()
        {
            /* Sa6a: You can put this somewhere outside or anywhere else,
             *       The idea is that while, items are being added to the queue, they are being dequeued,
             *       so without this you might end up in an infinite loop, if items are being added constantly and fater than they 
             *       are being dequeued(do not argue how fast the dequeue goes, does not matter)
             */
            int num_tasks_in_a_batch = 100;
            int counter = 0;

            //while true or while SiteController is enabled 
            //while (Enabled) --> Sa6a: you should not need this. If an item is added to the queue and the queue has item, the method will be called again
            //{
            try
            {
                await maxConcurrency.WaitAsync(); //Sa6a: What is this for?

                //lock (orderQueue) //Sa6a: I do not think you need a lock on the queue if it is concurrent
                //{
                if (orderQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    var batch = new List<OrderItemTask>();
                    while (orderQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        OrderItemTask my_task = null;
                        if (orderQueue.TryDequeue(out my_task))
                        {
                            batch.Add(my_task);
                        }


                        /* Sa6a: Explanation of this above, where the variables got declared
                         */
                        if (counter == num_tasks_in_a_batch)
                        {
                            placeOrderStrategy.PlaceOrder(batch); //Sa6a: I guess this is what you might believe would take all the time, and while this is happening items can be added to the queue
                            batch = new List<OrderItemTask>();
                        }

                        /*Sa6a: As the queue is concurrent and you will end up adding items, while they are being add here,
                         *      the user might try to stop the application and you might want to let them
                         */
                        if (Enabled == false)
                        {
                            break; //it should exit out of here
                        }
                    }


                    //Sa6a: You might have had 120 items in the queue. The first 100 got placed, now this will place the remainder 20
                    if (batch.Count > 0)
                    {
                        placeOrderStrategy.PlaceOrder(batch); //Sa6a: I guess this is what you might believe would take all the time, and while this is happening items can be added to the queue
                    }

                }
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let's printed it, so we know it has happened, if it ever does - " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                maxConcurrency.Release(); //Sa6a: I do not know what this is for either
            }
            //}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind blocking synchronously, you could use the powerful (albeit low level) functionality of [Monitor Wait/Pulse](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse). You would wait inside the method `ProcessOrderWorker`, and you would pulse everytime you change the condition that allows more items to be processed. Here is the waiting part:

```
void ProcessOrderWorker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (orderQueue) // acquire the lock
        {
            while (!Enabled || orderQueue.Count == 0) // waiting condition
            {
                Monitor.Wait(orderQueue); // here the lock is released
                                          // while waiting for a pulse
            }
        }

        maxConcurrency.Wait();
        lock (orderQueue)
        {
            if (orderQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var batch = new List<OrderItemTask>();
                while (orderQueue.Count > 0)
                    batch.Add(orderQueue.Dequeue());
                placeOrderStrategy.PlaceOrder(batch);
            }
        }
        maxConcurrency.Release();
    }
}
```

And here are the locations you should pulse:

```
public void Start()
{
    lock (orderQueue)
    {
        Enabled = true;
        Monitor.Pulse(orderQueue);
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    lock (orderQueue)
    {
        Enabled = false;
        Monitor.Pulse(orderQueue);
    }
}

void QueueOrder(OrderItemTask task)
{
    lock (orderQueue)
    {
        orderQueue.Enqueue(task);
        Monitor.Pulse(orderQueue);
    }
}
```